# Update intermediate model object using generic view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How can i update the existing object of intermediate model using generic view?

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
  date_joined = models.DateField()
  invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Currently i'm using generic views concept to update object, but I'm facing problem hoe to update field which exist in intermediate model?

If i generate modelform for **Group** class, then how can i update the associated field (intermediate model field) using generic view concept?

In above i want to update **invite reason** field

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some missing views in generic or [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) (which I highly recommend you if your are not already using them), and other people thinks in the same way...

Take a look at [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) project, it implements those *missing views*.